# Can NSNotificationCenter be used between different frameworks to communicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

An app can make internal use of NSNotificationCenter for different parts to communicate with each other, but can this be extended such that different frameworks can use it to communicate on iOS?

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter` is for *in-process* messaging, so code that is part of one process can communicate via `NSNotificationCenter`, regardless of which framework that code is in. You cannot use it to communicate between processes (say an app and an extension or two apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same app, frameworks all get executed on the same process. They just locate at different places in memory allocated by the app.

On the same running process, `NSNofitcationCenter` can communicate with each other no matter which framework the sender or receiver locates at.

If you are talking about app and its extension, they run on different process and thus `NSNofitcationCenter` can not send notification to each other. You have to use `CFNotificationCenter`